# Where is the password stored for ssh authentication?

Tags: ssh, security, password

It's known that when you're connecting to a wrong server via ssh and send your password  to it, your password comes in a plain text and a server saves it by default. Probably. I wonder, where I can retrieve it? I don't see it in `/var/log/auth.log`, although I do see all the attempts to authenticate.

Comment: there is a patch for sshd.

Comment: @IporSircer, where?

Answer (score 5):

Most existing versions of SSH servers do not, by default or any stretch of debugging, log the password of a failed login in plaintext anywhere, as that would be horribly insecure.

If you want that output somewhere, you'll have to look for a patch to `sshd` -- or write one yourself, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

> It's known that when you're connecting to a wrong server via ssh and send your password to it, your password comes in a plain text and a server saves it by default.

No. Any server that does that would be malicious. No reasonable software ever logs passwords entered by users. The password sent by the client is kept in memory for as little time as necessary to check whether it's correct, after that it's discarded, so that if the system is breached, the attacker won't be able to recover passwords that had been used before the breach.

If you want to log passwords, you'll have to use a specially-modified version of sshd. Obviously, do that only on a test system that isn't exposed to the network. Logging other people's passwords would be extremely unethical.